# Keep resizable children within parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I'd like to **keep the resizable elements within the parent element.**

***What I did:***
I gave already the `minHeight :` property and wile resizing I'm constraining the new height using `Math.max` to keep it at 30px height

***Expected:***
All resizable children elements should always be visible and minimally 30px in height.

***Issue:***
Somehow if you resize the lower elements, at some point vertical the big scrollbar appear and the resizable goes out of `containment:"parent"` (why?).
To recap - the page's vertical scrollbar should **never appear** an one should be always able to get to the "c" element.

```js
$(".resiz").not(":last").resizable({
  handles: 's',
  minHeight : 30,
  containment: "parent",        /* seems not to work?! */
  start:function(e,ui) {
    this.other= $(this).next() || $(this).prev();
    this.startingHeight = this.other.height();
  },
  resize:function(e,ui) {
    var diffH = ui.size.height - ui.originalSize.height;
    this.other.height( Math.max(30, this.startingHeight - diffH) );
  }
});
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box; margin:0;}
html, body{height:100%;}
#panel{
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:200px;
}
.resiz{
  height:33vh;
  width:100%;
  background:#eee;
}
.ui-resizable-s{
  height:3px;
  background:#08f;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="panel">
  <div class='resiz'>a</div>
  <div class='resiz'>b</div>
  <div class='resiz'>c</div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** [Seems related](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/ui-resizable-return-false-in-option-resize-event-to-prevent-further-resize) but the answer is not what I expected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the `height` of the last `div` but never the actual `div` being resized. So the `containment` grows with the last `div` being pushed and since the `containment` is applied on the `div` being resized, it's never applied.

So to solve your problem I think you need to `resize` the last `div` until it's a maximum `height`, and when it's the case prevent anymore resizing. You could do it like this, although it seems there could be a more efficient way. Still it'll give you some ideas:

```js
$(".resiz").not(":last").resizable({
  handles: 's',
  minHeight: 30,
  containment: "parent",
  /* seems not to work?! */
  start: function(e, ui) {
    this.maxHeight = undefined;
    this.other = $(this).next();
    this.startingHeight = this.other.height();
  },
  resize: function(e, ui) {
    var diffH = ui.size.height - ui.originalSize.height;
    
    //when next div is at max height, you prevent resizing of current div
    if (Math.max(30, this.startingHeight - diffH) == 30) {
      this.maxHeight = this.maxHeight || (this.prevHeight);
      ui.size.height = this.maxHeight;
    //until it's at max div you resize next div  
    } else {
      this.other.height(this.startingHeight - diffH);
      this.prevHeight = ui.size.height;
    }
  }

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#panel {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
}
.resiz {
  height: 33vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
}
.ui-resizable-s {
  height: 3px;
  background: #08f;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="panel">
  <div class='resiz'>a</div>
  <div class='resiz'>b</div>
  <div class='resiz'>c</div>
</div>
```